# "Learning" should be defined

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag "learning" seems to be undefined, and used inappropriately.

For example, it is being used on [Do 같이 and 함께 mean the same thing?](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/113/do-%EA%B0%99%EC%9D%B4-and-%ED%95%A8%EA%BB%98-mean-the-same-thing) which is just a straightforward question about the Korean language itself, and not a question about the act of learning Korean.

It should have a tag wiki describing what it means so that it's used correctly.

Comment: I think that [tag:learning] is a meta-tag and we should avoid them.

Answer (score 2):

According to the English Language and Usage (ELU) SE tag information, the tag 'learning' has the following description.

> useful for people learning English as a second language.

But, wait a minute. Isn't there anything that is not useful for people learnign Korean as a second language in Korean SE?

I think the linked question is related with 'adverb' and 'differnece'. ELU has only 75 questions under the tag out of 72,000 questions.

Based on my experience on ELU, tags don't play such a critical and important role as long as questions and answers are definitive, well-worded and researched.

I edited the tag in the linked question.